# Critical tunnel failure problem in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am facing critical tunnel failure problem in Blackberry while testing in Blackberry device.

I am appending interface=wifi while i am making request in device,but it shows critical tunnel failure problem.While testing in simulator it not showing any error.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=marine%20parade&sensor=false;interface=wifi
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be connecting over MDS or even BIS in which case ;interface=wifi is not required.

This is further explained in this video:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Networking-Transports-II/ta-p/446742

You may benefit from using the [ConnectionFactory](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/transport/ConnectionFactory.html) class in OS5 to avoid writing this sort of connection logic yourself.